# Don't rerender a control

Tags: filter, sapui5, rerender

Is there a way to tell a control, that it shouldn't rerender? Because in my component, there is a view, which dynamically adds messages to a dialog. Everytime I search for a letter in the searchfield, the view is refreshed to show the results. So after every refresh, the searchField is empty. This shouldn't happen.

EDIT: The problem is solved. Maybe another got the same problem, I've set Modelbinding and rerendered the SearchField, now it works. So the problem was not that it renders everything, the problem was, that the SearchField was not rendered ;)

Comment: Why does your view refresh at all? Can you tell us a little more about how everything is connected? What does the seachfields livechange event do?

Comment: I added the code above ;)